# Is Apple known to blacklist developers for conduct that takes place outside of official distribution channels?

Tags: ios-appstore, jailbreak, developer-program

Let's say I develop an app and sell it in the App Store. I make sure the app complies with all of Apple's policies. But outside the App Store, it's clear from social media that I'm in favor of jailbreaking. Maybe I develop apps that wouldn't be allowed in the App Store and distribute them over unofficial channels. Or maybe I have another version of the same app that doesn't adhere to Apple's policies, which I distribute outside the App Store. If Apple finds out about that, would that likely be a problem in practice, assuming I don't promote any of that stuff within my app or its App Store listing?

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking "If I enter an agreement with Apple and wilfully break said agreement, would that cause me problems in practice?". Nobody can answer that for you that.

Of course you can enter in an agreement with them and break it. If your app becomes as popular as Fortnite and Instagram combined, they'll probably find out and have it escalated within the relevant team at Apple. They might sanction you, they might not.

If you app is a niche app downloaded by few people that never complain about it, they might never find out - and even if someone at Apple is aware, that person might never contact the relevant team for escalation. There might be no consequence at all.

On the other hand, it's not a guarantee - there's a risk that the right person will you see you breaking the agreement, and then they could terminate that agreement.

A practical advice for you would be open up a company that is an independent legal person, and let that company enter into the agreement with Apple for distributing the app. Your interests in jail-breaking as a private person probably won't affect that agreement then.

Comment: My question was more about how they've handled similar situations in the past. Are there any known situations where this has happened? Are there any apps in the App Store that are widely known to be developed by someone who is active in the jailbreaking scene, which Apple *hasn't* taken down despite having had plenty of time to do so?

Comment: @flarn2006 Those are different questions. You should ask them separately.

Comment: @flarn2006 I have never heard of such a situation in the past, no. I cannot really see why Apple would specifically target those developers, if they are complying with App Store rules.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Actually that was my question. If you look at the title, you'll see it's asking whether or not Apple is "known to" do that.

Comment: This answer assumes that OP would be breaking an agreement (contract?) with Apple. But OP says that they'd “make sure the app complies with all of Apple's policies.” Do the agreements necessary to sell in the App Store necessarily prevent _any_ dissent, even if unrelated?

Comment: @gidds No, of course the agreements do not ban "any dissent". Essentially the files given by Apple to you as an enrolled developer (for example the SDKs) can only be used for developing apps that are distributed through one of the distribution channels in the agreement. If you use them to develop apps that break Apple's policies and distribute them through non-official channels - that would be breaking the agreement. Ofcourse get a lawyer involved if this is in any way important to you.

Comment: Take "jailbreaking" out of the question and replace it with anything critical of Apple and I would LOVE to know if they've got some internal system blacklisting folks from ever getting featured or perhaps even slow responses to issues.